How to debug a cmake-built binary that crashes in Release mode but not in Debug nor in RelWithDebInfo mode?
I'm developing an audio plugin that's supposed to run inside another (host) program. In most hosts this works fine but there's one in particular that causes my plugin to crash.
However this only happens when i set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release. It does not occur with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug or CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo, which makes this kinda hard to debug.
Also, the fact that RelWithDebInfo and Release are behaving differently leads me to believe that CMake+MSVC does not produce the exact same binary for those 2 modes.
Is there any way I can tell CMake+MSVC to produce the same binary for Release/RelWithDebInfo, but with additional pdb files for the "real" Release mode?

Maybe add lots and lots of logging.

When you get inconsistent behavior like that, the first thing to do is look for undefined behavior.  It has a nasty habit of changing symptoms based on seemingly random aspects of the environment.

@drescherjm you mean printf/to-file debugging? That's actually not a bad idea. Still hoping for something better to come up though :)

"CMake+MSVC does not produce the exact same binary for those 2 modes." - Probably, your project specifies different values for some configuration-specific variables or properties. Names of those variables/properties are ended with _RELEASE, _RELWITHDEBINFO or similar.

I normally always have a c++ logger. When I run into problems like this I increase the logging to log entry and exits of functions first just to narrow down the location of the crash then add logging of specific variables.

@Tsyvarev thanks! Just identified 2 instances of "set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ..." which had no matching RelWithDebInfo version.

Just for anyone stumbling into this: the problem turned out to be dynamic linking of MSVCRT. Once I static link, problems are gone. That's not a real answer of course, but good enough for my use case. I guess in any kind of host/plugin setup, you have to take these things into account.

I suspect all you really did was replace undefined behavior that failed spectacularly with undefined behavior that was benign.  I'd hardly call that "problems are gone".

@Mark Ransom sure, that may be the case. Although, please keep in mind that this is a host-program plus dynamically-loaded-plugin setup. At least to my mind, static/dynamic  linking of the c-runtime matters a great deal here. Just out of curiosity, what would be your course of action here? Maybe run through valgrind or something?

the problem turned out to be dynamic linking of MSVCRT Possibly mixing debug and release or mixing the runtime between dlls other dlls or your executable will cause UB.

Yes, it matters a great deal, because it moves things around in relation to each other.

@Mark Ransom just FYI there was indeed an out-of-bounds read which happened to "work" with static msvcrt. I'm still going with static link to prevent an update to the host program swapping the runtime out from under me and at drescherjm it has become painfully clear that yes, indeed, i do need a logging facility. Thanks for the help everyone.

I knew it!  Glad you found it, those can be very difficult to track down.  Since you weren't able to grab the attention of @drescherjm I just did it for you.
